# Conflicts when having multiple Angular @HostListener in different components

Tags: angular

It's my first time doing this.

I have **@Hostlistener** in *app.component* to listen for **'ESC'**. (acts like a global listener)

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
    public onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    ....... // listens for 'ESC'
}
```

and I have another **@Hostlistener** in *input.component* (listen for **'ENTER'** in input fields)

```
 @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    public onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    ....... // listens for 'ENTER'
    }
```

What happens now is when I am not in the input fields, 'ESC' will be detected. When I am in the input fields, 'ESC' will not be detected.

**Expected behavior:** 'ESC' should be detected even inside the input fields.

It seems like the global listener doesn't work like I expected. Is this the correct behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use directives to listen only to the input field. [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-copy-paste-blocker)

```
<input placeholder="Can't copy/paste" type="text" litsenEnter/>
```

Directive file

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[litsenEnter]'
})
export class LitsenEnter{
  constructor() { }

   @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
    public onKeydownHandler(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if(e.keyCode===13){
      alert("enter")
    }
    }
}
```

Global Escape event in app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {  HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) triggerEsc(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if(e.keyCode===27){
      console.log("global esc");
      alert("esc");
    }
  }

  name = 'Angular 5';
}
```

Comment: Hi is the Working demo showing about this question?

Comment: Yes.. try escape and enter key

Comment: Can I understand that when directives is use in Input fields (but not hostlistener in input components), it will not be conflicting with the global hostlistener in app.component?

Comment: Global listener will have higher priority than local directive listener. Only one will be executed at the time for a particular event like escape but if local listener event is different from global listener event it will not conflict